# How to include currency sign(₹) in crystal reports formula

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

In my project am using crystal reports 2008 for reporting purpose,in that I want to display the indian currency sign(₹).And I googled that also i didn't get any solutions.please suggest some solutions to add currency sign in crystal report formula.

Comment: Include it as part of formula itself (convert result to string with `totext()` then append currency symbol with `& " ₹`).

Answer (score 3):

These steps are for the version of Crystal Reports in VS2012, but I doubt they move these options around much, so you'll probably find this one in more or less the same location.

1. Right-click on the field and select "Format Object".
2. Select the "Number" tab in the popup window, if it's not already selected.
3. Press the "Customize" button.
4. Select the "Currency Symbol" tab.
5. Look for the "Currency Symbol" text box.

[image]